# Shockwave player/plugin for Linux?

Tags: linux, plugins, media-player

I remember reading, a few years ago, that there was no Macromedia Shockwave player that would run on Linux-based operating systems.

I have recently done some searching, but have only been able to find [old articles](http://www.ubuntux.org/shockwave-player-ubuntu-linux), also from a few years ago, describing how to work around this problem.

It's nearly 2010.  Has there been any progress towards a Shockwave player or plugin for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/alternates/

Seems Adobe still didn't write it. Note that there seems to be no player for Intel Macs either... Maybe Adobe simply wants to discontinue it?

People use Wine to run player for windows.

Comment: Yep, Windows shockwave + Windows firefox + wine is the way to do it.